# Taxi distance count to all lattice points at specified distance from the lattice origin and of a specified dimensionality?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, programming

### Setup of the problem

#### Description of the lattice

1. The problem is stated on a non-negative integer ($ℤ_{\ge 0}$) lattice.
2. The specification of *distance* is also a non-negative integer ($ℤ_{\ge 0}$).
3. The specification of *dimensionality* is positive integer ($ℤ_{\gt 0}$).
4. Lattice may considered to be labeled by vectors of non-negative integers ($ℤ_{\ge 0}$) of *dimensionality* length.

### Description of paths involved in the question

1. A trips will start from the origin, a constant array of $0$s, which is a lattice point in the lattice.
2. The set of destinations (a set of lattice points) is the set of lattice point whose sum of vector coordinates is *distance*.
3. The permissible transitions between lattice points are those which add an integer $1$ to exactly one of the vector components of the current lattice point's label vector.
4. A *path* is an ordered set of legal transitions from one lattice point to another.

---

#### The problem statement

Starting from the origin and transitioning under the above rules to a destination set, how many distinct paths are there?

The answer should be a formula or method that gives single non-negative integer answer for a given *distance* and *dimensionality*.

---

##### Remark:

Therefore, there are *dimensionality* legal transitions from a given lattice point. There is not stated upper limit of the magnitude of the vector components; but, effectively, a matrix of size $(\text{distance}+1)^{\text{dimensionality}}$ ought to be a sufficiently large work area for a computer implementation.

Comment: You have not said whether the destination set is a point or some points with the same distance from the origin or all the points of that distance or something else.  For a single point, it would be a multinomial coefficient $\frac{(x_1+x+2+\cdots+x_n)!}{x_1!\,x_2!\cdots x_n!}$, while for all the points at distance $d$ it would be $n^d$.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using Wolfram Mathematica:

```
taxi = Function[{distance, dimensionality}, 
    Total[(Multinomial @@ #1 & ) /@ 
      Union[Flatten[(Permutations[#1, 
           {dimensionality}] & ) /@ 
         (PadRight[#1, dimensionality] & ) /@ 
          IntegerPartitions[distance, 
           dimensionality], 1]]]];
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
 1 & 4 & 9 & 16 & 25 \\
 1 & 8 & 27 & 64 & 125 \\
 1 & 16 & 81 & 256 & 625 \\
 1 & 32 & 243 & 1024 & 3125 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

An English translation of the Wolfram Mathematica code (since this is *not* mathematica.stackexchange.com.

a) define a [function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html?q=Function) of two arguments *distance* and *dimensionality*,

b) compute the [total](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html?q=Total) of

c) the set of [multinomials](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Multinomial.html?q=Multinomial) ([Union](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union.html?q=Union) removes duplicates and [Flatten](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html?q=Flatten) reduces nesting level) of

d) the lists of [right-padded](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight.html?q=PadRight) with $0$s to length *dimensionality* lists of

e) the [integer partitions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html?q=IntegerPartitions) of *distance* to a maximium length of *dimensionality*.

2. By inspection of the table above:

$$
\text{dimensionality}^\text{distance}
$$

3. By attributes of Binomial and Multinominal:

```
Resolve[ForAll[{m, n}, Binomial[n, m] == Multinomial[m, n - m]]]
```

$$
\sum _{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} = 2^n
$$

N.B., this is also the number of binary integers of *dimensionality* bits, starting from zero.

The multinomial coefficient, $\text{Multinominal}\left[N;n_1,n_2,\ldots \right]$, denoted $\left(N;n_1,n_2,\ldots ,n_m\right)$,
gives the number of ways of partitioning $N$ distinct object sets,
each of size $n_i$ (with $N=\sum _{i=1}^m n_i$). See [**Multinomial**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Multinomial.html) in Wolfram documentation.

N.B., in general, the sum of the multinomial coefficients over the integer partitions of *distance* is also the number of base *distance* integers of *dimensionality* digits, starting from zero.

And, that leads back to the first answer.